# Проблема со скриншотом экрана python, windows, NOX

Tags: python, windows, screenshots

Пытаюсь снимать скриншот NOX, переключаюсь в него, жму кнопку "fullscreen" и начинаю делать скриншоты экрана. Проблема в том, что первый скриншот всегда правильный, всё ок. Но второй или такой же и тогда все последующие тоже равны первому (как будто экран не меняется, хотя это не так), или второй скриншот нормально берётся и тогда все последующие тоже нормально берутся (то, что действительно на экране)

Использовал как mss так и autogui, везде одно и тоже.

скрипт приблизительно такой

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import mss
import time
import sys
import pyautogui
import mouse as ms
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api
import gc
from pynput.keyboard import Key as KB_Key
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

Nox = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'NoxPlayer')
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(Nox)
win32gui.ShowWindow(Nox, 5)
time.sleep(0.5)
ms.move(1892, 47)
ms.click('left') #развернули в fullscreen
time.sleep(4)
pyautogui.screenshot() #первый скриншот

ms.move(1475, 246) #открыли окно в игре
ms.click('left')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.screenshot() #второй скриншот
```

дальше или всё заработало ок, или нужно перезапускать, пока второй скриншот и первый не будут отличаться.
Скорее всего что-то с драйверами, но куда копать не могу понять

Comment: а без фулскрина норм работает ?

Comment: Да, без фуллскрин работает нормально, проверил раз 10 - ни одного сбоя. А в фуллскрин на первом же разе